# How to convert JSON inserted created_at field in MongoDB to datetime objects in Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, datetime, twitter

I have been mining data from twitter for several weeks and without really thinking I inserted it directly into MongoDB directly as the JSON structure.

This appears to have caused a problem with the "created_at" field being in String format rather than datetime. This basically makes my indexes useless if I want to withdraw tweets from a collection between certain dates.

I am using python tweepy package and have been inserting the json tweets into mongodb like so:

```
    collection.insert(json.loads(data))
```

where data is like for example:

```
    {"created_at":"Tue Dec 03 23:07:53 +0000 2013","id":408009726509596672,"id_str":"408009726509596672","text":"this is some text"}
```

How can I programatically convert all of the String "created_at" dates into datetime objects within the collections?

What would be the best way to "find" the tweets and iterate through them from the database?

I have been trying something like this:

```
import pymongo, datetime

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

#access database
db = client.tweets

#access collection
collection = db.collection_name


tweets = collection.find({}) #just get all of the tweets in the collection.

for tweet in tweets:
    print tweet #how do I update the created_at field for each tweet in the collection  here?
```

**EDIT:**
I ended up using a hybrid of both Jose and Xcorat's answers.

For those that wish to do this purely in Python (continuing on from my code above) this is what I did:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    thedate = tweet[u'created_at'] #in my case I was storing the date as unicode not datetime.
    if(type( thedate ) == unicode):
        proper_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(thedate,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
        pointer = tweet[u'_id']
        collection.update({'_id': pointer}, {'$set': {'created_at': proper_date}})
        print('updated created_at from unicode to datetime\n')
    else:
        print('skipping as is already datetime...\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write a script on Mongo to do it?

in Mongo shell, something like,

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function (tweet){
    db.collection.update({_id: tweet._id}, 
                         {$set: {created_at: new Date(tweet.created_at)}});
});
```

just compress everything into one line, and cut/paste in the mongo shell, and ur done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to convert those strings into datetime you can use the `strptime` function, like this:

```
import datetime
s = "Tue Dec 03 23:07:53 +0000 2013"
proper_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(s,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
```

Now, you would have to iterate over all the tweets in your collection, fetching the old date and updating it with the new one. I don't know much about MongoDB, but my guess is that you could either use a loop, or do some kind of mass update.